# Device is not getting detected in eclipse.

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, usb, driver, ddms

I have MI pad, android version 4.4.4 KTU84P, MIUI VERSION-6.7.2.0(KFXMICH). I am developing under windows 8. Device is not getting detected in eclipse android DDMS. I have tried with some XIOAMI usb drivers but it didnt worked for me. Can any help would be appreciate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also use MI PAD for android development on windows 10. In my case it works fine. Before going further check these things -

```
1. USB debugging is on or not
2. adb devices command displays your device in list or not
```

If above two things are correct then it should connect correctly.